# Asp.net gives error when it renders some styles

Tags: asp.net

Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

and it highlights line 12 in this codes

Line 10:

Line 11:@ViewBag.Title - WeBlog

Line 12:   @Styles.Render("~/styles")

Line 13:

Line 14:

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057437/webgrease-error-on-styles-render-call-in-layout-cshtml-in-mvc4

Comment: i have done that and still gives the same error

Comment: It that giving you same error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Views/Web.config` has

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

And install the latest `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` through NuGet.