# The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference when using Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Tags: .net

I'm really stumped on this one and could use some advice. I created a new MVC (.NET framework) web application project in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019. Without making any changes I ran the project and receive the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease', Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

I started with deleting all files from Temporary ASP.NET Files, obj and bin folders then cleaned and rebuilt the solution. I then uninstalled WebGrease and its dependencies (Antlr and Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization) from the package manager and reinstalled the latest versions (Antlr v3.5.0.2, Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization v1.1.3, and WebGrease v1.6.0).

```
packages.config

<packages><package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net461" /></packages>

web.config

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Below is the Fusion log. I'm not sure what "Post-policy reference: WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624..." means or how to address it.

[image]

I'm not sure where else to look but I'm at the end of my wits with this and need help please.

Update: I found a couple more discussions on this topic. One of the [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851912/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-version-1-5-1-25624-culture-neutral) noted that this error is because Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3 internally references WebGrease 1.5.1.25624 even though the Nuget package itself has a dependency on WebGrease 1.5.2.14234. I tried all of the answers and suggestions but none worked. I also found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057437/webgrease-error-on-styles-render-call-in-layout-cshtml-in-mvc4) which is the exact problem I'm having but none of the answers or suggestions there work either.

Comment: If you've checked that the DLL in the bin folder is 1.6.0, then why do you tell everything to use version 1.6.5135.21930 ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The file version in the bin folder is 1.6.5135.21930.